# mysql service suddenly stopped working

Tags: mysql, redhat, mysql-cluster, mysql5.6

I am suddenly not able to start mysql service

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
Starting MySQL...... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid).
```

I have tried to do the following but still not working

```
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mysql
```

I am able to run `mysqld_safe`

```
    180114 23:05:07 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql-error/mysql-error.err'.
    180114 23:05:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
180114 23:05:11 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

But when i check for status I get following message

```
[root@host ~]# service mysql status
 ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, make sure your mysql is **not** running: `ps uax | grep mysql`. If not — just delete the lock file: `rm /var/lock/subsys/mysql`.

Then you should be able to restart mysql normally.